# Is it possible to pass the name of a subroutine to a string in VBA?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba, error-reporting

I'm constructing a database in Access with heavy VBA use.

It would be useful for error reporting if I could pass the name of an active subsoutine to a string. Is this possible in VBA?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes...manually  :-)

```
sActiveRoutine = "MySubName"
```

If you use a product like MZ Tools, you can make this quite easy by defining a custom header.
VBA does not have a way to return the name of the current proc.

Comment: It was automatically I was after - but "you can't" is kind of the answer I was expecting. Thanks!

Comment: Apologies, it's only good when the VBE is open.  If I find a way, I'll add an answer back.